# AWS Lambda: Using container image but still getting program path not found

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, containers

I have configured AWS Lambda function to use container image. I have build the image and uploaded it in ECR and using this image to run the lambda function.
I'm still facing errors:

```
[ERROR] PortScannerError: 'nmap program was not found in path. PATH is : /var/lang/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/:/bin:/opt/bin'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 234, in load_module
    return load_source(name, filename, file)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 702, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/task/app.py", line 36, in <module>
    nmScan = nmap.PortScanner()
  File "/var/task/nmap/nmap.py", line 132, in __init__
    raise PortScannerError(
```

When I run the script from the container manually it is running fine. While lambda executes this, I get the above error.

using this sample Dockerfile structure to create the Dockerfile:

````
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

# Copy function code
COPY app.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# Install the function's dependencies using file requirements.txt
# from your project folder.

COPY requirements.txt  .
RUN  pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"
RUN  yum install -y nmap

# Set the CMD to your handler (could also be done as a parameter override outside of the Dockerfile)
CMD [ "app.handler" ] ```

Do I need to specify the ENTRYPOINT?
````

Comment: Can you explain how did you prepare your function's container? In other words, how can anyone reproduce the issue?

Comment: I created Dockerfile, using python3.8 image from amazon. Created a file called app.py and add my code to it, created requirement.txt file which has python-nmap and requests to be installed by pip3. Also, I'm installing nmap by using yum install namp command and finally build the image.

Comment: And when I run the container using this image and connect it to that container, I'm able to run the script without any error. This error is only coming while running it via the lambda function.

Comment: I used this:
```FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

# Copy function code
COPY app.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# Install the function's dependencies using file requirements.txt
# from your project folder.

COPY requirements.txt  .
RUN  pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"

# Set the CMD to your handler (could also be done as a parameter override outside of the Dockerfile)
CMD [ "app.handler" ] ```
Do I need to change CMD filed?

Comment: Just edit your question with extra info.

Comment: Where exactly are you isntalling `nmap`? I don't see it in your dockerfile.

Comment: Just edited main question.

Comment: Are you sure that this is your real Dockerfile? Why was nmap line missing before?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236226/discussion-between-rukender-and-marcin).

Comment: Sadly I can't chat now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, it worked for me.

In the Lambda function, we can override the value of ENTRYPOINT, CMD, and WORKDIR.

So, I did the override by passing ENTRYPOINT, CMD, and WORKDIR(it defaults to `/var/task` for AWS Lambda).

Comment: How did you do that? What are the steps?

Comment: As I mentioned, I override the Entrypoint, CMD, and WorkDir value from the lambda function and it worked for it. 
It was working when I was manually connecting to the docker image and ran the query but it had some issue while running it via Lambda.

Comment: @Rukender what values you have passed for ENTRYPOINT, CMD, and WORKDIR. I am facing the same issue. I have bulit the Lambda container using the same dockerfile like yours